# Python: Type hinting for Gensim

Tags: python

In order to pass my gensim corpus and dictionary through the pipeline, I have made a convenience case class as follows:

```
class GensimCorpusAndDict:
    def __init__(self, corpus,  dict):
        self.corpus = corpus
        self.dict = dict
```

It would be helpful to get type hinting on the input parameters. I have read the docs but still not sure how to type hint on third party classes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read the [docs (PEP-0484)](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0484/#acceptable-type-hints):

> Type hints may be [...] and user-defined classes (including those defined in the standard library or third-party modules).

For example:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

class GensimCorpusAndDict:
    def __init__(self, corpus: np.ndarray, the_dict: pd.DataFrame):
        self.corpus = corpus
        self.dict = the_dict
```

Note: it is not good practice to use a variable name that shadows a built-in (in this case `dict`).

Comment: so anything defined in an import statement can be a type hint?

Comment: If it is a class, then yes

Comment: awesome. You are much clearer than the docs :) examples are helpful

Comment: But plug it in and try it yourself; try out if your IDE recognizes it and gives you the right hints